# Meteor Vagrant: Where should the project code files be?

Tags: windows, meteor, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have successfully configured Meteor on my Windows machine via vagrant along with running the sample app in the browser by following the tutorial given at https://gist.github.com/ahoereth/2607d2ee99103a0a9bc9.

For the last two hours, I have explored all of the Window's directories in search of the code created by `meteor create sampleapp` command, but I can't find any clue where the code is. As vagrant claims that code is in the Windows directory not the VM box, can anyone give me a hint where it could be hiding?

Comment: By the way, have you tried the [Meteor Windows preview](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/meteor-talk/355MsiNzfiE/lBUiFfvcYNYJ)? Aside from [some corner cases](https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/11), it works.

Comment: Giving it a try now but I have to make it work with vagrant. As everything is working but the code files are invisible.

Comment: You could try `ps aux | grep meteor` (or node maybe) to see where it is being run from.

Answer (score 0):

The directory that's shared with the Windows host is the `/vagrant` directory. In the VM, the home directory might be different, and won't be visible from Windows.

However, if you want to run the Meteor app from the shared directory, be prepared for a world of pain whenever you install a package that has a `:` in its name, as Windows won't support that character in the filename, and you'll get a cryptic error in the VM.

Since packages in Meteor 0.9+ regularly have `:` in their names, developing Meteor apps in the VM/Windows shared directory is a no-go.